# excel search and show value/data from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

so i have Sheet1 that is use to contain the list of my inventory data. what i want to do is in another sheet(Sheet2). i can search my Sheet1 data and display the data there ( for example when i type cheetos, only the cheetos item got display ). Help me guys, using VBA is okay or other method is also fine.

[image: this is the illustration of what i want to make]

Comment: There is an option in Excel, advanced filters which will let you filter a Range for a given criteria, in this case "*Cheetos*" look it up for if it helps

Comment: yep advanced filter actually help, do you know how can i Sum the quantity of that filetered value ? ex: i search for doritos then only sum the row with doritos in it

Comment: You can use `SUMIF` if you only need one criteria to filter or `SUMIFS` if you need multiple criterias to filter your sum.

Answer (score 0):

If your results don't have to be on a different sheet, you could just convert your data to a Table. Select Cells A1:D8 and click on Insert -> Table. Make sure "My table has headers" is clicked and voila!

Once formatted as a table, you can filter Product ID however you need.

If you do need to show these results in another sheet, VBA would be my go-to solution. Maybe something like this:

```
Public Sub FilterResults()
    Dim findText As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim foundRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'If there's nothing to search for, then just stop the sub
    findText = LCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4"))
    If findText = "" Then Exit Sub

    'Clear any old search results
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 5 Then
        For i = 6 To lastRow
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).ClearContents
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i).ClearContents
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).ClearContents
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & i).ClearContents
        Next i
    End If

    'Start looking for new results
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    foundRow = 6

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If InStr(1, LCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)), findText) <> 0 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & foundRow) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & foundRow) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & foundRow) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & foundRow) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i)
            foundRow = foundRow + 1
        End If
    Next i

    'If no results were found, then open a pop-up that notifies the user
    If foundRow = 6 Then MsgBox "No Results Found", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding VBA for this process as it can be done easily with excel's functions. If you would like to do it via VBA one could just loop through the list of products and find a key word, adding it to an array if the "Cheetos" is contained in the specific cell value using a wildcard like so:

This could be modified to run upon the change of the D4 cell if needed, and of course some modifications could be done to ensure that formatting etc can be done to your liking.

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim s_key As String, s_find() As String
Dim i As Long

Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook


Set rng = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B8")
s_key = wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D4").Value
wb.sheets("Sheet2").Range("C6:F9999").clearcontents
i = 0

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value Like "*" & s_key & "*" Then
        ReDim Preserve s_find(3, i)
        s_find(0, i) = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        s_find(1, i) = cell.Value
        s_find(2, i) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        s_find(3, i) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        i = i + 1

    End If

Next cell


wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C6:F" & 5 + i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(s_find)

End Sub
```